# can't generate stripe accountSessions

Tags: php, yii2, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe connected account
based on documentation of stripe
I should be able to create a session

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient([
// This is a placeholder - it should be replaced with your secret API key.
// Sign in to see your own test API key embedded in code samples.
// Don’t submit any personally identifiable information in requests made with this key.
"api_key" => 'sk_test_VePHdqKTYQjKNInc7u56JBrQ',
]);

try {
$account_session = $stripe->accountSessions->create([
  'account' => '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  'components' => [
    'account_onboarding' => [
      'enabled' => true
    ],
  ],
]);

echo json_encode(array(
  'client_secret' => $account_session->client_secret
));
} catch (Exception $e) {
error_log("An error occurred when calling the Stripe API to create an account session: {$e->getMessage()}");
http_response_code(500);
echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
```

}

However, I get this error:

```
"message": "Undefined property: Stripe\\Service\\CoreServiceFactory::$accountSessions",
```

it seems that $stripe->accountSessions doesn't exist! in stripe client object

Comment: Your code appears to match the documentation, https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_sessions/create?lang=php - except for the part of the client initialization. They are passing the API key directly as a string value there, whereas you are passing an array ...? And the example on github also passes just a string.

Comment: It seems that this functionality not implemented for Latvia, yet

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using an older version of `stripe-php` which does not have support for `AccountSessions`. This support was added in version 12.1.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1210---2023-08-31)), so you'll need to ensure you're using a version no older than that.

Note that starting with version 12.0.0, the SDK is now pinned to a specific API version. Pay very careful attention to the [breaking changes](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200---2023-08-18) noted for that release.